# Kernel facilities needed for C++

Tags: c++, c, operating-systems, kernel, stack-oriented

I'm working on a kernel for a proprietary embeded system. I've had no issues but I'd like to expand its capabilities directly. I made it run C. I did so pretty much by giving my kernel a stack.

My question is C only required a stack to be able to execute cross-compiled code. What beyond a stack would I need to provide at the kernel level for the execution of cross-compiled C++ code. That is, does it need a heap, more complex data types and structures, et al?

To me it's become a chicken or egg problem as anything that I think C++ might need is easily written in C++.

NB: I have endeavored to research this question here and elsewhere and have not found an answer to this specific issue. I have tried to make this a very specific question in accordance with the rules here, please help me if revisions are necessary.

Comment: you'll need the runtime library. If that's linked statically it won't need anything more than C.

Comment: Details are compiler and ABI specific.

Comment: "To me it's become a chicken or egg problem as anything that I think C++ might need is easily written in C++." Have you noticed that many components of the C++ standard library (especially the STL) and third-party libraries such as Boost are "header-only" classes? There is a strong correlation between your observation and the C++ libraries in that regard...

Comment: Since there are kernels written in C++, it seems self-evident that C++ does not need any kernel support at all, no?

Comment: No Jorg, with all politeness, there are some kernels that are capable and some that aren't, implying elements unknown are needed. My question was on the specifics.

Comment: @snowman excellent point. As it's a non-standard architecture I will have to remake the wheel, but at least I have access to all the interfaces and I'm sure I can figure out the rest. Very good point, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't strictly need a heap to run either C or C++ programs that are compiled for your platform, but if you want to use heap-allocated objects or memory blocks, then you will need a heap.

C++ uses heaps more than C code (ie routinely under the covers in libraries). In particular most use of the STL will want a heap, and C++ code uses the STL a fair amount. You can require a different allocator for STL containers, but I think forcing them to use the stack might be a step too far for most people, if its even possible at all.

Other than that, I guess it depends what code the compiler emits.

Comment: A note I should have mentioned is that I am quasi-emulating arm assembly by matching my machine instructions to the arm assembly instruction set names. So ultimately to allow for the native use of C++ I will need to get C++ standard library, runtime library, stl and a heap all working? Won't be easy, but I think I can handle that.